# Crash on com.google.android.gms. Server task (PingTask) got error statusCode=403

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have crash on some devices:
When app start, start google play services and I have crash

```
> BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for
> https://staging-usercontext.sandbox.googleapis.com/usercontext/staging1/controllerhub/ping?key=AIzaSyCBu4hYjXBYo4dv2I1TZah53ogQS60jQCM
> 08-01 10:17:06.016 2438-2438/com.google.android.gms.persistent
> E/ctxmgr: [BaseServerTask]Server task (PingTask) got error
> statusCode=403. [CONTEXT service_id=47 ]
> 
> com.google.android.gms.persistent E/ctxmgr:
> [ContextManager3PCredentialsVerifier]Failed ping response: network
> status=12 [CONTEXT service_id=47 ]
> 
>  java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid API Key for package =
> com.Filmgrail.android.bergen.debug. Status code received = 12
```

I use:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.1"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0"
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.0.0'
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:17.0.0"
```

But some devices do not this crash and work good

Comment: maybe again some issue with google services - recently they had some problems, and some systems were down for a while - I get similar errors since morning.

Comment: i have the same issues but it never lasts too long